# Count of rows where given columns of a DataFrame are non-zero

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, dataframe

I have a `Pandas` `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
MemberID    A    B    C    D
1           0.3  0.5 0.1   0
2           0    0.2 0.9   0.3
3           0.4  0.2 0.5   0.3
4           0.1  0   0     0.7
```

I would like to have another matrix which gives me the **number of non-zero elements for the intersection of every column** except for `MemberID`.

For example, the intersection of columns `A` and `B` would be 2 (because `MemberID` 1 and 3 have non-zero values for `A` and `B`), intersection of `A` and `C` would be 2 as well (because `MemberID` 1 and 3 have non-zero values for `A` and `C`).

The final matrix would look like this:

```
    A    B    C    D
A   3    2    2    2
B   2    3    3    2
C   2    3    3    2
D   2    2    2    3
```

As we can see, it should be a symmetric matrix, similar to a correlation matrix, but not the correlation matrix.

**Intersection of any 2 columns = # of `MemberID` having non-zero values in both columns.**

I would show some initial code here but I feel like there would be a simple function to do this task that I don't know of.

Here's the code to create the `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.3, 0.5,  0.1, 0],
                   [0,  0.2,  0.9, 0.3],
                   [ 0.4,  0.2,  0.5, 0.3],
                   [ 0.1, 0, 0,  0.7]],
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Any pointers would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: `df.A` has one element that is zero.  shouldn't `final.loc['A', 'A'] == 3`

Comment: Since you want `MemberId` to be treated as the index not a regular column, either do `pd.read_csv(..., index_col=...)` when you read in the dataframe, or else do `df.set_index(..., inplace=True)`

Comment: It's unhelpful to try to unilaterally redefine "intersection of columns" in a way that conflicts with every other definition out there. I would just call this "Count of rows where columns x,y respectively of a DataFrame are both non-zero", which is what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should to it:

```
z = (df != 0) * 1
z.T.dot(z)
```

[image]